# How to change visible tag in Visual Studio 2012 storyboard presentation?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, storyboard, powerpoint

I am using Powerpoint storyboard addon by Visual Studio 2012.
I added a tab group vertical and want to change the visible tab.
How do I set the visible tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is not supported. Once the shape is added to the slides, it is just like any other PPT grouped items. Sliders and progress bars got okay with it for smart behavior, but not the tabs.

The only workaround I found is to do so manually. If you want to make the second tab active:

1. Select and move the active first tab to third one's location.
2. Select and move the second inactive tab to the first one's location.
3. Select and move the active tab to second one's location.
4. Select and move the "white line" below the active tab.

Comment: thanks I did just that :), does not look awesome, but it do the job.